# Will viewDidLoad be called if i press home button and launch the app after 5 seconds

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, viewdidload

I know that `viewDidLoad` is called after your view is loaded. It is called only once when the view is initialized and pushed or presented.

But what I want to know is when I enter in `background state` for 4-5 seconds and open the app again.
will `viewDidLoad` be called again.

I Basically want to run a code everytime my app is launched.
How will I achieve that?

Comment: You can try it by put a `print` in your ViewDidLoad. If you want to run a code in everytime your app launch (when open app from background state too) you can call it at `applicationDidBecomeActive` in AppDelegate

Answer (score 3):

`viewDidLoad` will only be called one, when it is first loaded into memory.

Even `viewDidAppear` will not be called when your app resumes from a suspended state.

You can use the `applicationDidBecomeActive()` method from your `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Alternatively, you can register an observer for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` so that `doSomething` is called whenever the application becomes active:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // Set up the observer
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(self.doSomething),
            name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,
            object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDissapear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDissapear(animated)
        // Remove the observer
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(self.doSomething),
            name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,
            object: nil)
    }

    @objc func doSomething(notification: NSNotification){     
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: got it . Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help!